# Connection between the sql database and windows service

Tags: sql-server, database, windows-services

Can anyone help me with the connection string for how to make the connection between the sql database from windows service?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ADO .NET read up on the [`ConnectionString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) property of `SqlConnection`. For example:

```
var connStr = "SERVER=SomeServer;DATABASE=MyDb;Integrated Security=true;";
using (var db = new SqlConnection(connStr)) {
    db.Open();

    // other data access commands here
}
```